# Laravel Blade using @each, how to replicate enumerated internal counter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Consider the following view partial:

```
@foreach($comments as $index => $c)
    <tr{{ $index % 2 == 1 ? '' : ' class="row-color-alt"' }}>
        <td>{{ $c->user->present()->avatar_and_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $c->body }}</td>
        <td>{{ $c->added_on }}</td>
    </tr>                        
@endforeach
```

Here I can easily iterate `$comments` and `$index` will be an enumerated counter.

But if I convert to the usage of `@each`, such as:

```
@each('comment.item', $comments, 'c', 'comment.empty')
```

In this case `@each` will iterate `$comments` and include the view `comment/item.blade.php` each time. There is no `@foreach` in the view, so it will be like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ $c->user->present()->avatar_and_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $c->body }}</td>
    <td>{{ $c->added_on }}</td>
</tr>
```

How could I replicate the enumerated counter in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code, it looks like the iterator index is assigned to the `$key` variable. So, your `comment/item.blade.php` view should look something like:

```
<tr{{ $key % 2 == 1 ? '' : ' class="row-color-alt"' }}>
    <td>{{ $c->user->present()->avatar_and_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $c->body }}</td>
    <td>{{ $c->added_on }}</td>
</tr>
```

If you're on 4.1, you can check out the `renderEach` method in `Illuminate\View\Environment.php`. If you're on 4.2 or 5.0, the `renderEach` method is in `Illuminate\View\Factory.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `@for` loop instead.

```
@for($i=0;$i<= count($comments);$i++)
    <tr{{ $i % 2 == 1 ? '' : ' class="row-color-alt"' }}>
        <td>{{ $comments[$i]->user->present()->avatar_and_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $comments[$i]->body }}</td>
        <td>{{ $comments[$i]->added_on }}</td>
    </tr>                        
@endforeach
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but when using `@each` the collection is not available to iterate within the view.

Comment: So then you can use the `@for` loop in my example